# Why does big negative margin-right make absolute element no wrap?

Tags: css

**Update:**

The position value will change the width.

The JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caicai/mbtb5m7p/2/

---

Why does the width of div `.a2` equal to its parent's width, while the the text in the div `.a1` won't wrap?

The JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/caicai/mbtb5m7p/

```css
.r {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 22px;
    background: blue;
}
.a1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    margin-right: -9999px;
    background: green;
}
.a2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="r">
    <div class="a1"> 
        Why does this line no wrap. 
    </div>
    <div class="a2"> 
        Why does this line wrap. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You got a jsfiddle to show the world

Comment: Remove margin-right property

Comment: Just playing with the margin values in developer tools, the larger the negative margin, the more it increases the width of the `a1` div, losing the wrap effect.

Comment: @ManojKumar That may be the case but Zhiyong Cai is asking _why_ this happens.

Comment: You're simply making the right margin break out of `.r` containers 100px width. `margin-right:-10px` would see the the div wrap but it will be 110px wide. It's just `margin-right:-9999px` is so large it has given the effect of 'removing wrap' but if your text was long enough, it would eventually wrap.

Comment: @Matt Derrick `margin-right:-10px` then it will be 110px wide, but `margin-right:-9999px` then it not be 9999 + 100px width.

Comment: It won't be because the content won't push the div out to reach that size. However if you put in enough characters it will eventually become that wide https://jsfiddle.net/o07p1ba1/2/

Comment: @Matt Derrick It won't  be 9999 + 100px when the position of `.a1` is `absolute`, but it will be when the position of `.a1` is `relative`. I can't  explain.

Answer (score 3):

The `div.r` has a width of 100px and is placed relative.

The children `.a1` and `.a2` are placed absolute. The related on their (relatively placed) parent.

Without a negative margin, the children will take a maximum width equal to its parents size.

But, by adding a negative margin, you allow the children to "float over" its parents borders.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain how many px the `.a1`  will "float over".

Comment: Theoretically by 9999px, but as you can see, the default behavior is to make the div not wider as its content. When you reduce the margin-right to for example -25px, you'll see the effect better:  http://jsfiddle.net/mbtb5m7p/1/

Answer (score 2):

It's not that the content of `.a1` is no longer wrapping, it is that the content of `.a1` has no need to wrap because the available interior space has been made wide enough for the string inside it by your negative margin.

So your `div.a1` will essentially be the width of `.r` + the value of the negative margin, which is dragging out the right extremity and increasing the size of your div.

That's pretty much how the box model works, check it out [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) or [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)

Comment: #curious - The computed width value ISN'T the width of `.r` + the value of the negative margin. Also why would margin affect the content width in this case, based on default box-model?

Comment: you're right, not a literal addition, it just felt the easiest way to explain it (in much the same way as the w3c spec I linked to). So the width of `.a1` would have been 100px, however the right edge of the box has been moved 9999px to the right by the negative margin, making its interior width now 10099px ... therefore the string doesn't need to wrap ... (ha ha edits for my own maths on that simple sum, d'uh)

Answer (score 0):

The margin is something that depends on it's parent element(class/id) here class r for classes a1 and a2.

1) Now you have width:100px for parent class(Class .r) so all child classes(class a1 & a2) inherits same width.

2) There is no issue for class a2, that class is totally normal as no unique(different) property than parent class(.r), so behaves properly.

3) Now the case for class .a1, which behaves properly too till it finds **margin-right:negativeValue;**.

So first understanding margin, Margin is the space between class/element block and it's parent class/element block. For Example margin-left:5px; so that particular block starts after leaving 5px from left, respectively for rest three sides(top, bottom, right)

**Now negative margins, when used what it does is it trespasses their parent blocks boundary. That is it gets beyond the boundaries of their parents.
So here you specified margin-right:-9999px; so it gets beyond the boundary of class .r, still it might be giving you a thought that -9999px is a huge value, should throw the div beyond the screen, but as of limited text it only shows the area contained with text.**

Inserting more text in class a1 it will surely go beyond screen scope, but text should be more than enough.

[Graphical Explanation](http://www.divyashah.in/stackoverflow/images/margins.png) **Updated**

Comment: Thank you very much. But I can't understand your "but as of limited text it only shows the area contained with text.". As I test in jsfiddle, if the `position`of `.a1` is `relative`, the width of `.a1` will be 9999 + 100px while the `absolute` will not.

Comment: Glad that you found your answer, but i tried once again giving best explanation graphically.Still you find any issues feel free to ask. Here it is ---- [Link](http://www.divyashah.in/stackoverflow/images/margins.png)